# How to give user roles of different type in php?

Tags: php

I am working on this project with multi users. What i want to do is if a certain type of user is logging in then redirect to their respective page. Eg if it is admin redirect to admin page And if it user redirect to user page. And how do i give roles on who can view what and who can delete it?

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: i am just staring out with php. i have not yet coded this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to maintain this at DB level. This type of system is known as ACL (access control list). In such system there are following tables present:

1. user - user list
2. role - role list
3. user_role - user id mapped with role id
4. permissions - permission list
5. role_permission - role wise permission mapping

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. What about the logging in part?